# undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass for <% if @users.any? %>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am following the Micheal Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial. In the 12 chapter, I am getting this error.

I am trying to display the following and the followers, but I am not able to.

[image: This is the error I am getting.]

Following are the codes:

> show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @title) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
      <span><%= link_to "view my profile", @user %></span>
      <span><b>Microposts:</b> <%= @user.microposts.count %></span>
    </section>
    <section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      <% if @users.any? %>
        <div class="user_avatars">
          <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if @users.any? %>
      <ul class="users follow">
        <%= render @users %>
      </ul>
      <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

> relationship_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
 def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

> user_controller.rb

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
                                        :following, :followers]
  before_action:correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action:admin_user,     only: :destroy

    def index
  @users= User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end


    def show
  @user= User.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)

    end

    def new
  @user= User.new
    end

    def create
  @user= User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
       @user.send_activation_email
  flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

     def edit
  @user= User.find(params[:id])
     end

     def update
  @user= User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
     end

     def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
      redirect_to users_url
     end

    def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end


    private

      def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                     :password_confirmation)
      end




      def correct_user
  @user= User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless @user== current_user
      end


      def admin_user
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
      end

  end
```

Comment: What's in UsersController#show?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @RachitAhuja I have gone through your issue and following answers. It seems like as you are newbie, you are not getting it. You are messing up with File name. You should update placed your `show.html.erb` code into `show_follow.html.erb` . Following answer given by @Nirupa will fix your issue.

Comment: @DharmeshRupani I understood my blunder. Yes I am new to Rails, thats the reason I am following the tutorial. I was expecting something else, so somehow I managed to mess up the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your repository and seems like you have messed up the code, according to what you are following(Ruby on Rails - Micheal Hartl), this is what you need to change:

The code in your `show.html.erb` should be placed in `show_follow.html.erb`

[image]

After this follow the 12th chapter again and place the right code in show.html.erb.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the `show` action is actually using the `@user` instead of `@users` instance variable.

Your section for stats will not work since it's expecting what it looks like a collection of `User` as it would from the `index` action.

Since you have the action for `followers` which sets the `@user` and `@users` instance variables you have to visit that action instead and the code on your `show.html.erb` template will most likely have to move to the `show_follow.html.erb` template.

**UPDATE**

You need to remove this section from your `show.html.erb` template

```
<section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      <% if @users.any? %>
        <div class="user_avatars">
          <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if @users.any? %>
      <ul class="users follow">
        <%= render @users %>
      </ul>
      <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please see my repository at https://bitbucket.org/rachitahujadev/sample_app and tell me what do you think I need to change.
I have already created show_follow.html.erb.